# programatically invoke "Organize Imports" on VSCode / Typescript project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, import

I know it's possible to run tslint programatically over the entire project:

```sh
tslint --project tsconfig.json --config tslint.json --fix
```

but is it possible to invoke VSCode's `Organize Imports` quickfix over every file in a project?
[image: Organize imports on vscode dropdown]

I want to execute it over hundreds of files, and opening each file and running `Alt+Shift+O` for each one isn't feasible.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. You can do it with TSLint itself! Simply add the following rule to your tslint.json:

```
    "ordered-imports": {
      "severity": "default"
    },
```

now `tslint --fix` will automatically organize imports!

Comment: tslint's "ordered-imports" isn't quite the same as VS Code's "organize imports". The former sorts them, but maintains grouping, so imports in each group are sorted. VS Code move the imports into one group and then sorts them. It also removes linebreaks from imports.